# Ruby on Rails Web Application to iOS or Android app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I was to use the Ruby on Rails framework to build a web app what would be the best path for me to take to build a mobile application (iOS/ Android) that can speak and connect with the web application?

EG: twitter.com (DESKTOP) - twitter iOS or Android app.

Comment: Are you familiar with either language?

Comment: @KyleC I am familiar with Rails and Ruby and using the two. What languages and tools would be needed to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: I think you should try to come up with a more specific question. Are you looking for which gem to use connect to twitter? Or are you asking what language you might use to program iOS or Android? What?

Comment: @rainkinz If you have a look at my question once over you can see that I'm asking what language, tool and techniques can be used to use an existing rails application and make a mobile application that connects to it. The example is: twitter and the twitter app. Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It will take a lot of reading.

You will need to build an API on rails framework to communicate with an mobile application. Here are some good links for creating an API with rails:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning
      http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2013/06/13/building-awesome-rails-apis-part-1/

I would suggest using Devise for authentication and using their authentication_token to validate users network requests to your API.

http://matteomelani.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/authentication-for-mobile-devices/

Here are some helpful links that I bookmarked awhile ago to help.

http://pnhoang.tumblr.com/post/24160454924/build-a-rails-backend-api-for-an-iphone-client
http://www.takeofflabs.com/posts/8-Rails-and-iOS-a-sample-starting-setup
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ios-photo-sharing-geo-location-service
http://jessewolgamott.com/blog/2012/01/19/the-one-with-a-json-api-login-using-devise/

Best of luck

Comment: also one more question... would this kind of implementation be the only way of doing so? Also would this be able to be utilized to create a native mobile application? Thanks.

Comment: @John5 No of course not, there are many different approaches but I found the above with Devise being the best... Yes, you are still creating a native mobile application. Every time the mobile app needs data or performs an action on that data, you will be sending a request to your API.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the question is about Ruby on Rails to iOS/Andriod. Have you considered from Ruby to iOS/Andriod? Have a look at [RubyMotion](http://rubymotion.com). I think its easier with RubyMotion to connect mobile app iOS/Andriod with the Ruby application rather than via web application ROR.